# Extract untarred files from a tgz in linux

Tags: linux, vmware, tar, unzip

I have a large `.tgz` file which is of very large size(19GB). I started the untar operation in `vmware` last night but in the morning, I saw a blue screen of death. I dont want to waste time on untarring the files that are already done(5GB). How do I untar the files that are not yet untarred into the same folder without wasting time on 5GB.

Thanks.

Comment: The `tar` command accepts some arguments, however, that won't win much... maybe most of the time is spent in `gunzip`-ing that file.

Comment: Maybe something can be done but probably more time can be saved by starting from scratch. Ask your friendly admin for a really beefy virtual machine just for one night.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU tar:

```
tar xvf yourfile.tgz --keep-newer-files
```

Be careful though: the file that was aborted half way through will be also be skipped.